# Why would Puppet exclude a file resource without error?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, puppet, vagrant

The oddest thing is happening during this Puppet run (using `Puppet Apply`) and it has me perplexed.  I've tried my usual channels to find solutions but I cannot find anything on the topic.  I apologize for being so verbose, I just don't want to leave anything out :\

### -

### My Class

```
class c2c::profile::app::logio::stage_support {

  # Log.io plugin
  # Create plugin directories
  exec { "create_codec_dir":
    command => "/bin/mkdir --parents /etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs --mode=0775",
    creates => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs',
  }

  # Install plugin
  file { "logio_plugin_file":

    # update: added in response to a serverfault comment
    ensure  => file,

    path    => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb',
    mode    => '0775',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/c2c/logstash/logio_codec.rb',
    require => Exec['create_codec_dir'],
    notify  => Service['logstash'],
  }

}
```

.. and my **Puppet run is skipping the `logio_plugin_file`** instruction (or, for whatever reason, is not copying the file).

### -

### Logs, Etc

The debug log is rather large, and did not want to paste the whole thing, so here is every line in the Puppet run that mentions 'logio_plugin_file', but I'll gladly provide more if needed.

```
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/seluser: Found seluser default 'system_u' for /etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/selrole: Found selrole default 'object_r' for /etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/seltype: Found seltype default 'etc_t' for /etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/selrange: Found selrange default 's0' for /etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb
..
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/require: requires Exec[create_codec_dir]
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]/notify: subscribes to Service[logstash]
..
Debug: /File[logio_plugin_file]: Autorequiring File[logstash_codec_plugins]
```

**/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml**

The term 'logio_plugin_file' is only mentioned as part of two `Puppet::Util::Log` entries, and no `File[logio_plugin_file]` entry exists.

Below is a quick snippet of those two entries:

```
- !ruby/object:Puppet::Util::Log
  level: !ruby/sym debug
  time: 2013-12-06 17:30:38.009095 +00:00
  tags: 
    - debug
    - file
    - logio_plugin_file
    - class
    ... (25 more ) ...
  line: 41
  source: /File[logio_plugin_file]/require
  file: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/c2c/manifests/profile/app/logio/stage_support.pp
  message: "requires Exec[create_codec_dir]"

  .. further down, mostly the same except ..

  message: "subscribes to Service[logstash]"
```

### -

### Strangeness

This file is included within a large catalog, with dozens or hundreds of other classes, but what's weird is if I include this class directly using a quick testing manifest (also using `puppet apply`), it works like a charm.  (Although I did have to remove the service requirement)

```
node default {
  class { 'c2c::profile::app::logio::stage_support': }
}
```

.. and I get this in my output ..

```
Notice: /File[logio_plugin_file]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}41d00952843b8159b95ce4fcd8015cda'
```

.. and this in `last_run_report.yaml` ..

```
File[logio_plugin_file]: !ruby/object:Puppet::Resource::Status
  resource: File[logio_plugin_file]
  file: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/c2c/manifests/profile/app/logio/stage_support.pp
  line: 40
  evaluation_time: 0.023071
  change_count: 1
  out_of_sync_count: 1
  ...
```

### -

### Additional Points, Info, and Tests

- I only just added the `Notify => Service['logstash']`, and this behavior was occuring before I did so.
- No errors are emitted
- I added a few `notify{}` calls in my `stage_support` class to ensure it was being properly included in the catalog, and it is.
- `Exec['create_codec_dir']` is creating my directory
- I tried changing the `path` param to `logio2.rb` to see if the class
- I tried requiring `File['logio_plugin_file']` from another resource.  The requiring resource ran, but the file was not created.
- **Update:** I tried reducing my file type call to only include the `title` plus `ensure`, `path`, and `source`, which had no effect.
- **Update:** I tried renaming the resource, (e.g. `logio_plugin_file_x`), which did not help.

  ```
  [root@dev ~]# puppet --version
  3.2.3

  [root@dev ~]# facter --version
  1.7.2

  [root@dev ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
  ```

### -

### Important Note

This problem comes on the tail end of me doing a code restructuring, so that's almost certainly to blame, but I am not able to troubleshoot this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is that resource included in the run report's resource list (`/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml`)?

Comment: It is mentioned twice, yes, as the 'source' and one of the 'tags' for two `!ruby/object:Puppet::Util::Log` entries.  Those messages are: `"requires Exec[create_codec_dir]"` and `"Autorequiring File[logstash_codec_plugins]"`.  Otherwise, a search for `logio_plugin_file` does not return any additional results within that file.

Comment: When running puppet apply with my testing manifest (as mentioned as the "strangeness" above), there is an additional last_run_report.yaml entry that does not exist in the standard run: `File[logio_plugin_file]: !ruby/object:Puppet::Resource::Status` .. I'm guessing that is what you were looking for in your question.

Comment: That's.. very strange.  Try adding `ensure => file` for paranoia's sake?  And I think it is going to be, but verify the resource is in the catalog file at `/var/lib/puppet/client_data/catalog/hostname`?

Comment: I added `ensure => file` to no effect.  I thought you might have nailed it there and perhaps something had overrode the default action.  I checked for the file also, but my `/var/lib/puppet/client_data` directory is empty, might be because I am using `apply` instead of `agent`, I'm not sure.  I'm tempted to rebuild the VM from scratch, but I worry that I might sweep the problem under the rug and have to fight it again later on if I do.

Comment: I have so many ideas about what could be wrong, but all are defeated by the fact that it runs properly when isolated in my testing manifest.

Comment: Ok, making headway.  Changing the `path` to `path    => '/etc/logstash/logio.rb',` seems to work.  Not sure why yet.

Comment: Huh - it might be something related to that autorequire of `File[logstash_codec_plugins]`?  That should be the only thing that changed from the path change.  How does that file resource relate to the explicitly required `Exec[create_codec_dir]`?

Answer (score 1):

As expected, the source of the problem turned out to be simple, though I still do not understand why Puppet did not fire an error about this:

**profile/logstash.pp:** (elsewhere)

```
file { 'logstash_plugin_sub':
  path      => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash',
  ensure    => 'directory',
  owner     => 'root',
  group     => 'root',
  mode      => '0775',
  require   => [ File['logstash_plugin_sub'] ]
}
```

Note the circular reference in the require: `File['logstash_plugin_sub'] -> File['logstash_plugin_sub']`

The resulting behavior is very weird, and I found the problem using this test:

```
file { "logio_plugin_file_a":
  path    => '/etc/logstash/logio.rb',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/c2c/logstash/logio_codec.rb',
}
file { "logio_plugin_file_b":
  path    => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logio.rb',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/c2c/logstash/logio_codec.rb',
}
file { "logio_plugin_file_c":
  path    => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/logio.rb',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/c2c/logstash/logio_codec.rb',
}
file { "logio_plugin_file_d":
  path    => '/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash/codecs/logio.rb',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/c2c/logstash/logio_codec.rb',
}
```

The idea being, principally, try adding my file at deeper and deeper locations in the tree.  This idea came to me as a result of being able to change the `path` in my original example, and achieve success.

So, the following was created:

```
/etc/logstash/logio.rb
/etc/logstash/plugins/logio.rb
```

But the two deeper resources were skipped, so I knew my problem centered around `/etc/logstash/plugins/logstash`.   Upon close inspection, I found the circular reference.

Hope this helps someone, and thank you to Shane Madden for his time.

Comment: Wow, good find - it's crazy that it's not throwing a big angry error message on that!  That seems like a bug, might be worth reporting to them?